# How do you access Gardens of Briar in the Sorcery! series?

Tags: sorcery-2

In Sorcery! 2, there is an area on the bottom of the Upper Kharé map labelled *Gardens of Briar*. It appears to have a path going through it and a cave/mine, but attempting to follow the path there doesn't give you the option to go that way at the fork, as far as I can tell. There is a house at the fork, though, that seems to be pointless during my playthroughs, so perhaps there is an option there that I have not realized.

[These tweets](https://twitter.com/inklestudios/status/477930411700785152) seem to indicate that somehow, there *is* a way.

I've read hints that it is not accessible until Sorcery! 4, so an answer from that game, or any other Sorcery! game, is acceptable as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This response contains minor spoilers:

> After playing it, I can assert that in Sorcery 4 you DO get to visit the gardens of briar. I'll explain how to get there in the following spoiler.

Here's how (more spoilers):

> When entering Mampang via the goblin kitchen, and exiting through the tunnel to the alley, you'll be approached by a beggar who'll take you back to the gardens, and even explain why you weren't able to enter it before.

Comment: While this is the most useful answer so far, the whole point of the spoiler tag is to be able to write full spoilers, so adding more details would only improve the answer.

Comment: @ZAD-Man Fair enough, I'll update the answer with _yet another_ spoiler

Answer (score 0):

ZAD-man, I have inquired the same thing as you but asked Inkle's support email, and they responded by stating that it is currently not possible to get into the Gardens of Briar, however in the future there will most likely be a way. I can post screenshots if you need proof of this.

Comment: Oh, that's perfect! I don't _need_ proof per say, but that would definitely make the answer complete. Also, it would finally demonstrate the answer for the Internet at large, so people with the same question can see.

Comment: Any chance of getting those screenshots? Apparently this question has been bumped, so it'd be good to have them in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can't find the stone fruit where the foot is myself but the green ring is dropped by the blind goblin in the mines in the first game (spoilers)

Only achievable in new game plus you first need to get the skull cap from the first guy in cantopi then go to the mines encounter the blind goblin and cast tel give him a message don't get greedy and he drops a green ring doesn't drop if you kill him

Answer (score -1):

You need the green metal ring to cast ZIp; cast it near the "foot" and box full of stone fruit.

Comment: What "foot" are you referring to? And stone fruit, for that matter. If you could give a more detailed location that would be a big improvement, and pointing out where you can get a green metal ring would be even better.